# Reload page without disrupting currently running Javascript

Tags: javascript, reload

Is there any way to reload a page without resetting Javascript code that is currently running on the page (for example, being run via the Chrome dev console)?

My situation is that I have a page that I need to keep reloading and running code on automatically. However, whenever I refresh the page using window.location.reload( ) it stops any Javascript that I'm currently running on the page.

Is there any way that I can keep refreshing the page but keep running the same code?

Comment: you can frame it or use ajax to update the page without reloading

Comment: You can't refresh the page but you can use ajax to load new content from the server and update the page. Why do you need to reload the page without stopping the JavaScript?

Comment: It's preferable to use `AJAX`; you can view :http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx

Comment: you might also be able to use the newer SharedWorker() threads.

Comment: Thanks dandavis, using ajax to update the page works perfectly.

Comment: @Chthonian You can post an answer to your own question if a method works perfectly for you. You'll earn rep if it gets upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to dandavis for this answer.

By using ajax, I was able to select a div that encompassed the page and selectively reload it. Effectively, this means that the contect of the page was refreshed.

The code looks something like this:

```
$('#mydiv').load(document.URL +  ' #mydiv');
```

Example (where middle is the ID of the div):

```
$('#middle').load(document.URL +  ' #middle');
```

Comment: Note: if you are running across domains, make sure CORS is enabled

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you could dynamically update your page... *but* if it isn't possible...

You can host your entire page need refreshing inside a frameset, and do your important JS outside your frameset inside the framepage. [Example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_frames.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Without AJAX, I might decide to refresh the entire page every 30 seconds, but with AJAX, I can just make a lightweight request to get the tiny bit of information I need.

Using AJAX to submit forms isn't always the best bet. Asides from not really giving you a clear advantage over posting the form normally, you break conventions such as browser history (although some browsers now include JavaScript "states" as pages in the history).

*Example :*

```
        $.ajax({
        url: form_url, 
        type: form_method,      
        data: form_data,     
        cache: false,
        success: function(returnhtml){                          
            $("#result").html(returnhtml); 
            $("#loadingimg").hide();                    
        }
        error: function (xhr, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Vikrant29/Uwcuz/2951/)